# dynamically filtering a List using Reflection in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, uwp

Hi I am working on a UWP application using the MVVM pattern.

### What parameters do I have:

I have an `IDictionary<string,bool>` with the `key` with the name of the property `(string)` and the `value` as a `bool` that should be the value of the property.

### What I am trying to achieve:

I want to create a generic `List<T>` filter method that would take in the parameter I have defined above and return all items from that List in which the `Key` property has the `Value` value from the `IDictionary<string,bool>`. My best guess was to use `Reflection` but got lost in the process. I need help.

### The Code:

**My Class of which the List is:**

```
public class fooClass
{
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public bool AdminAccess { get; set; }

    public bool ChildRestrictions { get; set; }

    public List<ChannelInfo> RestrictedChannels { get; set; }
}
```

**My property for setting the collection of filters**

```
 private IDictionary<string, bool> filterBasedOnBoolCollection;
    public IDictionary<string, bool> FilterBasedOnBoolCollection
    {
        get { return filterBasedOnBoolCollection; }
        set
        {
            filterBasedOnBoolCollection = value;
            FilterByBoolValue(value);
            RasiePropertyChanged(nameof(FilterBasedOnBoolCollection));
            RasiePropertyChanged(nameof(GetAllUsersWithFilterIfAny));
        }
    }
```

**My Getter Property for the filtering process:**

```
public ObservableCollection<fooClass> GetAllUsersWithFilterIfAny
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerable<fooClass> intitialAllUsersFilter = AllUsersCollection;


            //For Name containing "string" filter.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterQueryString?.Trim()))
                intitialAllUsersFilter = intitialAllUsersFilter.Where(x => x.FooName.ToLower().Contains(FilterQueryString.ToLower()));

            //For BoolProperty value matching filter.
            if (FilterBasedOnBoolCollection?.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < FilterBasedOnBoolCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    var propName = FilterBasedOnBoolCollection.Keys.ElementAt(i);

                    var value = GetType().GetProperty(propName);

                    bool propMatchingValue = FilterBasedOnBoolCollection.Values.ElementAt(i);

                    //var first = intitialAppTypeDeviceFilter.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Select(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(propName)).ToList());
                    fooClass tda = new fooClass();
                    var first = tda.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
                    var S = first.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propName));
                    var p = first.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(x, null));

                    intitialAllUsersFilter = intitialAllUsersFilter.Where(x => (bool)x.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(x, null) == propMatchingValue);
                }
            }

            return intitialAllUsersFilter.ToObservableCollection();

        }
    }
```

The above is all I've tried. I tried to separate the linq query too just to see the outputs. Clearly I don't have it figured out yet because as soon I try the codes I get an error at the intermediate window:

`{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<Intouch.BlackBox.Outlets.AllDeviceDataOutlet>}
                Error: Evaluation of method                     System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView 1[Intouch.BlackBox.Outlets.AllDeviceD                ataOutlet].get_Items() calls into native method                           System.Func 2[Intouch.BlackBox.Outlets.AllDeviceDataOutlet,System.Boolean].Invok                e(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not            supported.`

---

**Please Note** The filter process is below:

1. Type the matching name (Containing clause of the string).
2. from the resultant Data (of those who's name has the matching keywords from the query), fetch the items in which `AdminAccess == true && ChildRestrictions == false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to be able to do filtering for arbitrary classes or just for one fooClass? In the latter case, you can do something like this:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, Func<fooClass, bool, bool>>();
filters["AdminAccess"] = (obj, val) => obj.AdminAccess == val;
filters["ChildRestrictions"] = (obj, val) => obj.ChildRestrictions == val;

var filterValues = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
{
  {"AdminAccess", true},
  {"ChildRestrictions", false}
};

var list = new List<fooClass>()
{
  //....
};

IEnumerable<fooClass> filteredQuery = list;
foreach(var f in filtervalues)
{
  filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(foo => filters[f.Key](foo, f.Value));
}

var filteredList = filteredQuery.ToList();
```

It introduces a bit of maintenance if the field list changes, but it's far simpler than anything with reflection, IMO.

Warning: code is not tested, is just for reference (and possibly doesn't even compile).

### Edit:

Even with this solution, you can let every filterable class implement a simple interface, and access that for filtering. As an example:

```
public interface IFilterableByFlags<T>
{
  Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool, bool>> GetFilters();
  IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilters(IEnumerable<T> collection, Dictionary<string, bool> filterValues);
}

public class FooFilters : IFilterableByFlags<fooClass>
{
  public Dictionary<string, Func<fooClasss, bool, bool>> GetFilters()
  {
    var filters = new Dictionary<string, Func<fooClass, bool, bool>>();
    filters["AdminAccess"] = (obj, val) => obj.AdminAccess == val;
    filters["ChildRestrictions"] = (obj, val) => obj.ChildRestrictions == val;
    return filters;
  }

  public IEnumerable<fooClass> ApplyFilters(IEnumerable<fooClass> collection, Dictionary<string, bool> filterValues)
  {
    var filters = GetFilters();

    // this could be written using Linq Aggregate, but I prefer an
    // explicit loop. Simpler error handling (omitted here for brevity)
    foreach(var f in filtervalues)
    {
      collection = collection.Where(foo => filters[f.Key](foo, f.Value));
    }

    return collection;
  }
}
```

In this example I'm implementing filters in an external class, but one could easily extend the fooClass to incorporate the filters, mixing and matching this code to suit your needs.

Reflection is more complicated. Potentially a lot. If you want to follow that rule, make note that accessing to property values via reflection is a lot slower, so if you have to manage a lot of data some `Expression<T>` trickery will probably be needed. Oh, and this code can be easily extended to support non-boolean filters.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although for this I'll need to update the dictionary inside the method each time I add a new filter right? because if so then I can't use it as I have to create a .dll out of my project and what all filters to provide have to be flexible throughout

Comment: just the issue with the answer is that it's not necessary to provide both the bool `AdminAccess` and `ChildRestrictions` for search, it can be that I only want to filter where `AdminAccess` is true doesn't matter if `ChildRestrictions` is true or false or vis.ver or it's filtered by both the `bool` both have to be true or false or one is true and other is false

Comment: It's not required to provide all the filters! You can just provide a filterValues with only the properties you need. The foreach loop iterates over filterValues, not over filters. So only the filters provided are applyied.

Comment: and the filters that I don't provide would not be considered as false? is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. I would suggest you try to understand the code, if you want to use it.

Comment: So sorry for all the dumb questions. I don't have much experience using the `func` keyword. Great. the code works just fine. thanks

Comment: I just accepted it as an answer. Although I was looking more on the terms of not making up a set of rules for filter on both sides the app and the library. regardless, thank you for the answer and the constant support